# Sorting vector based on another sorted vector

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I have got a `vector1` of `pair`, sorted by an `int` key:

```
std::vector <pair <int,string> > vector1;
//6 5 1 8 4 2
```

Then I have another `vector2` consisting of numbers contained in `vector1`:

```
std::vector <string> vector2;
//1 5 6 8
```

How do I sort `vector2` with the same keys as in `vector1`? I want to get:

```
unsorted: 1 5 6 8
sorted:   6 5 1 8

unsorted: 6 5 1 2 4 
sorted:   6 5 1 2 4
```

Comment: *"vector2 consisting of numbers"* and `std::vector<string> vector2` ?

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes. Later I will need that

Comment: I didn't quite get it, so you want to sort vector2<int> with the same priority as they appear in vector1? So for example, if vector1 is [2, 4, 3] and unsorted vector2 is [3, 4] after sorting it should be [4, 3], is that right?

Comment: @Misho Tek Exactly

Comment: And what happens if vector2 has some kind of number n that is not present is vect1? And is there any such possibility?

Comment: @Misho Tek It's never gonna happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If vector2 consists of numbers that always appear in vector1, you can map numbers from vector1, for example vector1 is `[3, 2, 4]` and vector2 is `[4, 3]`;

1. Map all elements to indexes for exampe `3->0, 2->1, 4->2`
   (keys are numbers and values are indexes). Use map or hashmap for
   it.
2. Now loop through vector2, for each element search for it in the map and replace it with value from map: `4 becomes 2, 3 becomes 0` so now vector2 becomes `[2, 0]`
3. Now use `sort(vector2.begin(), vector2.end());` vector2 becomes `[0, 2]`
4. Now loop through vector2 and for each element i replace it with vector1[i]:
   `0->3` (because number at the 0th index in vector1 is 3), `2->4` (because number at the 2nd index in vector1 is 4).
   Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You might create a map of values, something like

```
void SortAccording(std::vector<int>& vec, const std::vector<std::pair<int, string>>& ref)
{
    std::map<int, int> m;

    int counter = 0;
    for (auto& p : ref) {
        m[p.first] = counter++;
    }
    std::sort(vec.begin(),
              vec.end(),
              [&](int lhs, int rhs) { return m.at(lhs) < m.at(rhs); });
}
```

Comment: I do not understand it at all. I'm using C++98

Comment: We can now use C++17, so tag properly if your limited to C++98/03